# Go to next cell of a table view from the viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I have a question regarding a Swift project.
I have a `TableViewController` with multiple cells, and when I click on them I go to a `ViewController` where data is passed from the `tableViewController`.

I want to implement a button in the `ViewController` that allows me to display the `ViewController` with the content of the "next cell" from the table view controller. For instance, I clicked on the 2nd cell of the table view controller, so I go to the `ViewController` that displays the data corresponding to that cell, and then when I click on that "next" button in the `viewController` I want to display the content of the 3rd cell of the table view controller. How do I do that in a clean way?

Here is the code I use to pass the data from `tableViewController` to `ViewController` :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let a = articles {
        return a.count
    }
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ArticleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let article = articles?[indexPath.row]

    if let a = article {
        cell.textLabel?.text = a.articleName
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 18)
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        if let i = a.tableViewImage {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: i)
        }

    }

    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowArticle" {
        let articleVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ArticleViewController

        guard let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell,
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) else {
                return
        }

        articleVC?.article = articles?[indexPath.row]
    }

    }
```

In the `viewController`, to show the right article, I wrote this in the `viewDidLoad()` (my `viewController` shows a web view of an article, and I have a class `Article` where `articleLink` comes from):

```
    if let a = article {
        articleWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(a.articleLink, ofType: "html")!)))
    }
```

I have linked a `nextButton` in `Main.Storyboard`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
```

I'm relatively new to Swift, and have no idea how to do it (my main problem is because I declare my data in the `tableViewController`, and I don't see how I could stay in the `ViewController` and "import" data from the `tableViewController`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code of `TableViewController's` `prepareForSegue` like this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowArticle" {
        let articleVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ArticleViewController
        guard let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell, let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) else {
            return
        }
        articleVC?.articles = articles
        articleVC?.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        articleVC?.article = articles?[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Now add two global variable in your `ViewController` like below also change your next button click like this

```
var articles: [article]!
var selectedIndex: Int!

//Now your button click
@IBAction func nextButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    if ((self.selectedIndex + 1) < self.articles.count) {
        self.selectedIndex++
        let nextArticle = self.articles[self.selectedIndex]
        articleWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(nextArticle.articleLink, ofType: "html")!)))
    }
}
```

I don't know you are using `NSArray` or `Array` so create the `articles` array object same as you created in `TableViewController`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You are a life saver, thanks !
It works like a charm, I just changed a.articleLink to nextArticle.articleLink in your answer in nextButtonClick (if anyone needs this in the future).

Thanks for the help :)